# Hibernate mapping entities with ManyToOne through a intermadiate table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this relationship between classes

Persona

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "estudiante")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "est_id", referencedColumnName = "per_id")
public class Estudiante extends Persona {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "est_acudiente")
    private Acudiente acudiente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "est_madre")
    private Persona madre;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "est_padre")
    private Persona padre;

    @ManyToOne
    private Grado grado;

}
```

Grado

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "grado")
public class Grado {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "gra_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Short id;

    @Column(name = "gra_nombre")
    private String nombre;

    public Short getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

The thing here is a student(Estudiante) can be in differents degrees(Grado) through the time, so there will be an intermediate table to save all degrees a student has been, but I just need to know the student's actual degree and I can't get how to achieve this with hibernate.

Hope you could help me and sorry for my english.

Good regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your mapping One Estudiante can have only one Grado

Estudiante and Grado are in **Many to One** Relation 
So Estudiante can have multiple Grado

So your relation should be like this

**Estudiante.java**

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "estudianteId")
private List<Grado> lstGrado;
```

**Grado.java**

```
@JoinColumn(name = "estudianteId", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne
private Estudiante estudianteId;
```

To find out latest Grado you can to few things

1. If all Grado inserts were in Order you can iterate  latest gra_id
2. Add new column in Grado and mark latest record as Y and others as N

Comment: Thanks! I was out of my head, I add the Matricula class:

    class Matricula {
        private Estudiante estudiante;
        private Grado grado;
    }

Answer (score 1):

If GRADO contains many ESTUDIANTEs and an ESTUDIANTE links to many GRADOs, you are looking at a many to many relationship. That way you would get the linking table.

cheers!